# Can a mleccha marry a non virgin?

Tags: marriage

If a woman has sex with a man it is considered a gandharva marriage or a type of marriage and marriage is considered for life in Hinduism. So if a mleccha were to marry a mleccha woman who is not a virgin like is common among mleccha culture, wouldn’t it be adultery?

Comment: by definition, mlecchas are those who live outside the tenets of Vedic dharma (beyond 4 varnas). for them, Bhagavan has given different shastras like Torah, Bible, Quran. And they also have rules for adultery, virginity etc.

Comment: What if there is a mleccha man that follows Hinduism?wouldnt it be adultery for him?

Comment: hinduism is a path that is followed, not a destination to be reached.. so, yes.

Comment: Yes, under non-criminal age that is according to your country rules. Also if she wants it. Go for it. If you follow Hindusim you are a Vedic, not a mleccha.

Comment: Yes, under non-criminal age that is according to your country rules. Also if she wants it. Go for it. If you follow Hindusim you are a Vedic, not a mleccha.